# Unlock cells based on both column and row headers?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table which looks like this (it changes dynamically).
[image: Table]

I am trying to make a macro which would unlock only the "light yellow" cells = row 1 contains "Forecast" as a value and column I contains "Actual" as a value. I would later protect the sheet so the user would be able to change value only in these cells.

In conditional formatting I use this formula:
`=(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1;COLUMN();4))="Forecast")*(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW();COLUMN($I$1);4))="Actual")`
But I've failed to make something like this work in VBA.

Comment: In VBA, try looping through each cell in column I. If its value = "Actual", then - for the same row - change `Locked` property of columns O-U to `False`. Let me know if you get stuck!

Comment: Thank you @JustynaMK. I managed to make it work.

Comment: Tom good job! Take care :)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone wondered how to do it.

```
Sub Lock_Cells()
Dim startCol As Long
startCol = WorksheetFunction.Match("Forecast", Range("1:1"), 0) 'Define in which column Forecast starts

Dim i As Long 
For i = 2 To Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If Cells(i, "I").Value = "Actual" Then 'Loop through values in column I
        Range(Cells(i, startCol), Cells(i, "U")).Locked = False 'Unlock cells
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```